# Replace an array parameter in a url request using URLSearchParams and $.param()

Tags: javascript, jquery, get, request

I would like to change the url request while clicking on a link one of the element of an array. For example :

```
?foo[]=1&foo[]=2
```

to

```
?foo[]=1&foo[]=3
```

I use `URLSearchParams` with methods `.getAll('foo[]')` and then `.set('foo[]', array)`
Finally, I use jquery method `param()` to generate a correct url string (as I was not able to use `URLSearchParams.toString()` with an array -- the result is always foo[]=1&3).

This is working, but if I had other parameter in the request I would like to keep, it becomes complicated to regenerate the url.

For example :

```
?foo[]=1&foo[]=2&bar=3&bar[]=4&page=1
```

to

```
?foo[]=1&foo[]=3&bar=3&bar[]=4&page=1
```

I have many parameters, so I would like to avoid the rebuild the entire query object to pass to `$.param()`. So :

1. Is there any option to get the whole array from `URLSearchParams` without using any loop.
2. Is there any trick to use `URLSearchParams.toString()` with arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you'll need to do is remove the `foo[]` entry, then iterate the values array from `.getAll('foo[]')` and `.append()`.

For example

```js
const usp = new URLSearchParams([
  ['foo[]', 1],
  ['foo[]', 2],
  ['bar', 3],
  ['bar[]', 4],
  ['page', 1]
])

console.info('original:', decodeURIComponent(usp.toString()))

// get all 'foo[]' entries
const foos = usp.getAll('foo[]')
// incremenent the last value
foos[foos.length - 1]++

// remove 'foo[]'
usp.delete('foo[]')

// iterate values and append
foos.forEach(foo => usp.append('foo[]', foo))

console.info('updated:', decodeURIComponent(usp.toString()))
```